# Keep getting same values for rand(n1..n2) within a loop

Tags: ruby, random, hashmap, random-seed

```
for i in 1..numAthletes
    randomNum = 0;
    runningTotal = 0;

    randomNum = rand(30..89);
    athleteTimes['swim'] = randomNum;
    runningTotal += randomNum;

    randomNum = rand(90..119);
    athleteTimes['run'] = randomNum;
    runningTotal += randomNum;

    randomNum = rand(120..360);
    athleteTimes['bike'] = randomNum;
    runningTotal += randomNum;

    athleteTimes['total'] = runningTotal

    athleteTotal[i] = athleteTimes;
end
```

When I run the above code, I keep getting the same value sets for the hash being stored inside the subsequent hash. I'm assuming there is something I need to do to reset/reseed the random generator, but I'm unsure how to do this with in Ruby.

I tried using `r = Random.new` and using `r.rand(n1..n2)` hoping this would force the generator to be reseeded, but it did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You re-use the same `athleteTimes` hash in each iteration and therefore change existing values in the `athleteTotal` hash.

Instead you need to create a new hash in each iteration:

```
number_of_athletes.times do |i|
  swim = rand(30..89)
  run  = rand(90..119)
  bike = rand(120..360)

  athlete_total[i+1] = {
    'swim'  => swim,
    'run'   => run,
    'bike'  => bike,
    'total' => swim + run + bike
  }
end
```

Furthermore you will notice, that I re-wrote your example using common Ruby idioms like snakecase variable names, no `;` at the end of a line.

Comment: I been bang my head on this for too long that the obvious escaped me.  This works awesome.  Also I was able to just move my `athleteTimes = Hash.new(0);` inside the loop and it fixed it as well.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad I could help. I suggest that you try to follow common [Ruby coding styles](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide). Your code looks more like JavaScript than Ruby...

Comment: Thanks @spickermann, I have a back ground in Java, C++, PHP, JavaScript, etc.  This is my first dip into Ruby.  I'll take a look at the link you provided.